# Unable to open Linked Access 2003 table to MS SQL Server in VBA code

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, vba

I have a table in Access 2003 that is linked to a MS SQL server table.
I am able to go into the Access table, manually update it and see the changes
reflected in the MS Sql server table.

However, I'm unable to even just open the table and put the result in the  record set in my VBA code.

```
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("dbo_tbl_EventLogs", dbOpenTable)
```

(rs is always at nothing)

The same line of code works on a 'local' Access table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using `dbOpenDynaset` option which is used by default for linked tables or stored queries whereas `dbOpenTable` is used for local tables as mentioned for [OpenRecordset()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff820966.aspx) method:

> If you open a Recordset in a Microsoft Access workspace and you don't
>   specify a type, OpenRecordset creates a table-type Recordset, if
>   possible. If you specify a linked table or query, OpenRecordset
>   creates a dynaset-type Recordset.

```
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("dbo_tbl_EventLogs", dbOpenDynaset)
```

Comment: You beat me to it, although I was going to suggest `... , dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)`.

Comment: Indeed, if linked MSSQL tables have an identity column, `dbSeeChanges` may need to be specified depending on recordset operations.

Answer (score 1):

You need to connect to your DB using ADO. Is simple and easy. Just change to your info and enjoy it.

```
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

ServerName = "yourServer,yourPort(example: 1442)" 'Enter your server name and a port here
DatabaseName = "yourDBinTheServer" 'Enter your  database name here
UserID = "yourUserID" 'Enter your user ID here
Password = "yourPassword" 'Enter your password here

Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
Set cn = New ADODB.Connection

cn.Open "Driver={SQL Server};Server=" & ServerName & ";Database=" & DatabaseName & ";Uid=" & UserID & ";Pwd=" & Password & ";"
rs.open yourQueryAsString, cn
```

Comment: this would make me connect directly to the MS Sql Server database.  I want to use a linked table

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you store the user credentials used to connect to the database...
(attribute dbAttachSavePWD)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, an answer really needs to demonstrate the solution.  Please [edit] to provide example code to show what you mean. Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead.